# distribution of the maximum of independent poisson random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_i$ $i=1,\dots,n$ be independent poisson random variables with $X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$ 
then we define $X = \max_i X_i$

how does $X$ distribute?

Is easy to see that

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq k) = \prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{e^{-\lambda_i}}{j!}\lambda_i^j$$

But i don't know how to find a close formula.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the inner sum should start from $j=0$, but apart from this, I wouldn't expect that a nice closed formula for the distribution of $X$ exists.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of a common parameter, see, e.g.,

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4373.pdf

One can show that

$\Pr(X \leq k) = (\Pr(X_1 \leq x))^n = (Q(k+1, \lambda))^n$,

where $Q(k+1, \lambda) \equiv \frac{\Gamma(k+1, \lambda)}{\Gamma(k+1)}$,

and $\Gamma(x, \lambda)$ is the (upper) incomplete gamma function.

It's also possible to derive a bound on the maximum of the expectation which does not depend on the independence.  See problem 2.18 in "Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence" by Boucheron, Lugosi, and Massart.